# Adobe Flash CS6 - AIR export error "CreateWinProces failed"

Tags: air, flash-cs6

By trying to debug an AIR project in Flash CS6 (Windows XP) this error occurs and Flash doesn't responds anymore:

> CreateWinProcess failed with error 2. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.

This error even comes up with a new and empty project .fla file.
I already updated the Air runtime and Flash to the latest version.

How to fix this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you find solution to your problem? If yes, can you please post it? I am facing the same issue and am not able to find any solution elsewhere.

Comment: Didn't found a solution yet.